# jQuery Tabs animations not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

For some reason I can't get any animations to work with my jQuery UI tabs.  I've tried many of the examples from [here](http://www.eduteka.org/ajax/tabs3/) with no success.

Here is how I am laying out my tabs.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabsHeader">
        <h1>PARTNERSHIPS</h1>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span class="toothIcon"></span>The Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span class="avatarIcon"></span>Join Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>header</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class="content">
        <p>some text</p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" />
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE" />
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="CITY OF PRACTICE" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

init like so:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'fast' });
```

or

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 } });
```

The tabs work how they are suppose to, but with no animation? Anyone know why?

Comment: You need to provide the plugin. However, in the link you provided, it seems the plugin download no longer exists.

Comment: I'm not actually using that library, I got the tabs UI from http://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old API doc. Check this http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-hide

You need to use `hide` and `show` properties to define animations, not `fxFade` etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/U287r/

Comment: This did the trick. fadeIn and fadeOut works but if I do $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 } }); i get nothing... I think it's because I didn't include 'show'

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery Tab's [`hide option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-hide) and [`show option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) for animations.

You can go about this by using a `boolean`, `number`, `string`, or `object`.

---

***BOOLEAN:***

> When set to true, the panel will fade in with the default duration and the default easing.

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ 
     hide: true,
     show: false   
 });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/5/

---

***NUMBER (in milliseconds):***

> The panel will fade in with the specified duration and the default easing.

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ 
     hide: 1000,
     show: 2000
 });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/6/

---

***STRING:***

> The value can either be the name of a built-in jQuery animation method, such as "slideDown", or the name of a jQuery UI effect, such as "fold". In either case the effect will be used with the default duration and the default easing.

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ 
     hide: 'fade',
     show: 'explode'   
 });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/4/

---

***OBJECT:***

> If the value is an object, then effect, delay, duration, and easing properties may be provided.

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ 
     hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 200 },
     show: { effect: "fade", duration: 200 }    
 });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/1/

Comment: @Romes sure thing, I have added a more detailed explanation of the animations. Hope this helps!